# is there any way to define these classes of react in each of single file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `index.html` with `react.js`, `react.dom.js` and `browser.min.js` along with `app.jsx`.

In `app.jsx` there are two class `App` class and `HelloWorld` Class.
When these two components are kept in single file, this whole system works
but when i define `App` and `HelloWorld` in each single file this doesn't work.

I see this code at reactjs website in section adding-react-to-any-website

```
<!-- Index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Wizkumar MsgInc </title>
        <script src="../js/react/react.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/react/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/react/browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="App"></div>
        <script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/app.jsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
//App.jsx
class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                i am {HelloWorld}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('App'));
```

When I put `HelloWorld` in a different file and App in different file this code did not work so is there any possible way to put these classes in different each file and program works.

Comment: Hi Rahul, did you include `HelloWorld.jsx` on the page or import it within `App.jsx`? It looks like you're starting a App from scratch and not wanting to add it to an existing site, in this case I'd recommend https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started. This will get you started quickly, eventually you can dig deeper into how it works and learn about Webpack etc.

Comment: yes i include 'HelloWorld.jsx' it gives and error in consloe.  'Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWorld is not defined.'

Comment: ```                                                                                                                    
 <script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/helloWorld.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/App.jsx"></script>                                                    ```  its a sequence of file when seperated

Comment: just dont forget to export that class from new file.
`export default HelloWorld`
and import it where you want and use like Component `<HelloWorld .../>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Making Class access to Global Scope is a solution i found for this problem

```
//helloWorld.jsx
class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
var global = window || global;
global.HelloWorld = HelloWorld ;
```

**Here using global we have made this class available globally**

```
//app.jsx
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                i am {<HelloWorld/>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('App'));
```

**Now lets look at index.html**

```
<!-- Index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Wizkumar MsgInc </title>
        <script src="../js/react/react.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/react/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/react/browser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="App"></div>
        <script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/app.jsx"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/helloWorld.jsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Now this will work, because HelloWorld Component is #globally available to app component**

```
Question was define these classes of react in each of single file
if in case the application grows large, Solution is put all classes
in each separate files and make them available Globally
```

**#HappyCoding**

Answer (score 1):

Since HelloWorld is a component you should use it as component `<HelloWorld />`

```
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                i am <HelloWorld />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

if you want to use it in a different file you have to export the component

Comment: i did the export as said by @witold-komorowski , down below he is commented and in return console has a new error for me `exports is not defined`

Comment: maybe `export !== exports`, that's why

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way. Put in other file your class like this:

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And in the top of main file add:

```
import HelloWorld from './myfile'
```

Use brakets `<HelloWorld />` for component class

Comment: let me try this

Comment: there is a new error now its says `exports is not defined`

Comment: `export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}`

Comment: `import HelloWorld from './helloWorld'

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                i am {HelloWorld}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('App'));
`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to include second file like app.jsx:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/app.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/HelloWorld.jsx"></script>
```

BTW: It's commong way to use webpack to build all files in signle bundle and only 1 file is needed to be included on page.

BTW2: Here you can check how officialy recomended to start project on react: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: **no i have included these files. and got an error  **                                                              `Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWorld is not defined`      even sequence is                    `<script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/helloWorld.jsx"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="../js/react/textClass.jsx"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Export HelloWorld and import in App.js as shown below. Also custom components should be written in <> and variables in {}

HelloWorld.js

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import HelloWorld from 'HelloWorld';

    class App extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    i am <HelloWorld />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('App'));
```

Comment: yes same thing i did . and console return a new error `exports is not defined`

Comment: even i copied ur code and run it here still its `exports is not defined`

Comment: then remove export default from HelloWorld.js and in the bottom add module.exports = HelloWorld;

Comment: You don't need to use .jsx extension, you can use .js and create your project from using create-react-app cli from node js. It comes with built in webpack which handles your downgrading your es6 and above code to es5 to run on older browsers

Comment: after `module.exports = HelloWorld;` it returns ` module is not defined`

Comment: is know how create-react-app works. i work well in that environment. at all the time you cant be in that environment  . i am looking for solution of this without create-react-app. If u wann see my little react-app i hava built then visit [link](https://www.oceangreen.ml/msginc/login.php) You can ask me further credential

Answer (score 0):

In your app.jsx file import properly the file by

```
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HelloWorld />
    );
  }
}
```

And in HelloWorld.jsx export with name you import in app.jsx

```
class HelloWorld extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World !!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```